# Weird content in the clipboard after copy from Excel

Tags: java, excel, swt, clipboard

I'm trying to get the content of the clipboard in my application to ensure excel compatibility, using :

```
Clipboard clipboard = new Clipboard(Display.getDefault());
String contents = (String) clipboard.getContents(TextTransfer.getInstance());
```

The problem is, if I have on one column [1, 2, 3], and I select cells [1] and [3], then in the clipboard content I found

> 1\r\n2\r\n3\r\n

instead of just 1 and 3. In other words the clipboard does not seem to handle disjointed cells.

Does somebody have an idea of what is going on ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with SWT, because I get the same result when copying to a text editor from Excel. It's an interesting question nontheless though.

Comment: The clipboard holds more than the string. You are only returning the string. When you paste into Excel, more than just the string of the values is considered and you get 1 and 3. If you paste the same thing into Notepad then you get 1, 2 and 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible outside of Excel for a couple of reasons:

1. As @Baz pointed out, text editors also respond by printing the contents of all three cells. Even Word does this.

   For example, say I have a spreadsheet open in Excel with the following contents:

   [image]

   And then in Word I insert a new Excel spreadsheet:

   [image]

   When we attempt to copy and paste only the cells containing `A` and `C`, we get the expected result:

   [image]

   However, if Excel is not open when the new spreadsheet is added to the Word document, we get:

   [image]

   To me this seems to indicate that when Excel is still open when the spreadsheet is added in Word, the instance of Excel is shared somehow and that's the only way it knows which cells to paste. (*I'm using Office 365*)
2. As far as I can tell, Excel does not put anything into the clipboard to indicate which cells are selected. That would make sense given the results of pasting into Word after Excel has been closed, but to further the point this is the XML that Excel puts in the clipboard when only the cells containing `A` and `C` are copied:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
> <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
>     <Styles>
>         <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
>             <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
>             <Borders/>
>             <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
>             <Interior/>
>             <NumberFormat/>
>             <Protection/>
>         </Style>
>     </Styles>
>     <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
>         <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="1" ss:ExpandedRowCount="3"
>         ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
>             <Row>
>                 <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">A</Data></Cell>
>             </Row>
>             <Row>
>                 <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">B</Data></Cell>
>             </Row>
>             <Row>
>                 <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">C</Data></Cell>
>             </Row>
>         </Table>
>     </Worksheet>
> </Workbook>
> ```

Notice that the data for all three cells is present in the clipboard contents, and there is nothing to indicate which cells are selected.

To get this XML, I extended the `ByteArrayTransfer` class for the "XML Spreadsheet" type to just write to a file:

```
public class ExcelTransfer extends ByteArrayTransfer {

    private static final String TYPE_NAME = "XML Spreadsheet";
    private static final int TYPE_ID = registerType(TYPE_NAME);

    private static final ExcelTransfer _instance = new ExcelTransfer();

    private ExcelTransfer() {
    }

    /**
     * @return
     */
    public static ExcelTransfer getInstance() {
        return _instance;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    protected int[] getTypeIds() {
        return new int[] { TYPE_ID };
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    protected String[] getTypeNames() {
        return new String[] { TYPE_NAME };
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    protected void javaToNative(final Object object, final TransferData transferData) {
        // ...
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    protected Object nativeToJava(final TransferData transferData) {
        if (!isSupportedType(transferData)) {
            return null;
        }

        final byte[] buffer = (byte[]) super.nativeToJava(transferData);
        if (buffer == null) {
            return null;
        }

        final File f = new File("excel_clipboard.xml");
        try {
            f.createNewFile();
            final FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fo.write(buffer);
            fo.close();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

With the cells already copied, run with:

```
public static void main(final String... args) {
    new Clipboard(Display.getDefault()).getContents(ExcelTransfer.getInstance());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your well detailed answer !